# Exit Code to be logged into output file

Tags: powershell

I have a log file and I need certain lines to be written to an output file with exit codes. For example if the line contains **ERROR** I need an output file to write the line number and an exit code range of 0-20. Here's an example of the log file.

For example I need my output file to look like this:

```
1 1
2 10
3 2
4 3
5 4
```

Here is an example of a log file:

```
2019-01-14 21:36:37 INFO: Executing user is OFFICE\adaccountdeletion
2019-01-14 21:36:37 WARNING: Reading configuration file E:\AdAccountDeletion\Script\v1.1.7\Jan 14\Remove-StallUserObjects.xml
2019-01-14 21:36:37 INFO: Successfully parsed configuration file
```

Comment: Do you want the exit code to be random or assigned sequentially? What exit code do you want in the case where 0-20 is used within a single script run? Your output suggestion is a bit ambiguous. Is the required format `linenumber[space]exitcode[space]linenumber[space]exitcode`?

Comment: so yeah, i need the exit code to be between 0-20, it doesn't matter if its sequential or not but i need the code to repeat itself once the 0-20 codes are used and there are more then 21 codes.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. I guess this is up to your preference. We can do random error codes within your defined ranges and use the same code throughout each execution of the script or select a random error code each time an ERROR is found. We could cycle starting with 0-20 and then start back over at 0 again. This could also be done per run or per error.

Comment: yeah cycling 0-20 and start over again is fine, when it finds ERROR start from 0 to 20 then reset back to 0, and since its outputting the line number i can quickly jump to that line even though there is lets say 20 exit code 3s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For randomized codes (one code per script run):**

```
$file = Get-Content Log.txt
$lineNumber = 0
$errorCode = (0..20) | get-random
$warningCode = (21..40) | get-random
$output = ForEach ($line in $file) {
    $lineNumber++
    if ($line -cmatch " ERROR: ") {
        "$lineNumber $errorCode"

    }
    if ($line -cmatch " WARNING: ") {
        "$lineNumber $warningCode"

    }
}
$output
```

**For cycling codes (one code per match):**

```
$file = Get-Content Log.txt
$lineNumber = 0
$errorCode = 0
$warningCode = 21
$output = ForEach ($line in $file) {
    $lineNumber++
    if ($errorCode -eq 21) {
        $errorCode = 0
    }
    if ($warningCode -eq 41) {
        $warningCode = 21
    }
    if ($line -cmatch " ERROR: ") {
        "$lineNumber $errorCode"
        $errorCode++

    }
    if ($line -cmatch " WARNING: ") {
        "$lineNumber $warningCode"
        $warningCode++

    }
}
$output # outputs line numbers and exit codes to console
$output | out-file "errorLog.txt" # outputs line numbers and exit codes to file errorlog.txt
```

Comment: is there a way to make the code repeat itself? for instance, ERROR codes will only be 0-20 but WARNING codes are 21-40 and if i have more then 21 codes i need it to repeat

Comment: @Brad, I updated with examples cycling the codes and randomizing the codes